# What is the difference between input_shape and input_dim in keras?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

Currently i am learning deep learning and stumbled upon these confusion:
when to use input_shape and input_dim parameter.

shape of my data is (798,9) and these has 8 input variable and 1 output variable so my question is when making a sequential model whats the difference between:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=12,input_shape=(6912,),activation='relu' ))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'))
```

AND

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=12,input_dim=8,activation='relu' ))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'))
```

so can anyone explain in detail about how to choose input_size and input_dim and whats the difference between it?

Comment: It is very well explained in the official docs https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/ . Pass an `input_shape` argument to the `first layer`. Some 2D layers, such as Dense, support the specification of their input shape via the argument `input_dim`.  If the input is a 1-D array, then you can just use input_dim as a scalar number and there's no need to use shape.

Answer (score 9):

You need `input_shape = (8,)`, which is exactly the same as `input_dim = 8`.

Your final `Dense`, naturally, needs to have 1 unit only. For regression you might want `activation = 'linear'` in the last layer and for classification you will want `'sigmoid'`.

For higher dimension data, you will need `input_shape = (dim_1, dim2, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks I understand partially because in mnist data why we are taking input shape as 784? Can we write 28 instead of 784

Comment: You can `(28,28)`, it's 3D data (when you consider the batch size). But your model must be built accordingly to work with 3D data. --- Those `(784,)` examples are flattening the data to use FCN (fully connected networks). --- The CNN (convolutional neural networks) would use the images correctly with shape `(28,28)`.